# Hide column in a datatable with an if

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm new to jquery and datatable but learning quickly.

I want to hide specifics columns according to the value of a variable that I'll test with an if. But I don't know where to put said if and the code to hide the columns.

HTML:

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered table hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0" >
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Have</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Good</th>
    <th>Day</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 $('#table_id').DataTable({
   "processing": true,
   "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
    "ajax": {
        "url": "somewhere.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Have" },
        { "data": "A" },
        { "data": "Good" },
        { "data": "Day" } 
    ]
 });
} );
```

Pseudo code for the if

```
 if($_POST('something') =="hey"){
  hide column 1 and 2;}
```

Comment: This should be tagged `[jquery-datatables]`, but for some reason it's not letting me change it via edit.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()

Comment: I tried to add it this tag but couldn't either. And yes I saw the api but it looks like the code need to be somewhere specific because when I tried it didn't work.

Comment: @freedomn-m tried too with the same result. Also tried removing an unecessary tag (PHP)

Comment: @Romain do you want the "if" condition within your datatable initialization?

Comment: I'm struggling with where to put it moslty. I'm a bit confused

Comment: Within the document.ready, you could make an ajax call (your $_POST) and then in the `success:` (or `.done()`) callback you make the call.   If this is onload, then you probably don't want the extra POST and want to supply the result for the condition when rendering the page.

Comment: @freedomn-m, they're synonyms http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/synonyms so when you edit it in, it'll automatically be remapped to [datatables].

Comment: @BhargavRao thanks for the explanation.  I guess I mixed it with the comment that says don't use this for 'datatable'.  But it's clear now, so no worries.

Answer (score 17):

#### HTML-sourced or JavaScript-sourced data

Use [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option to define a callback fired once table has been initialized. Use [`columns().visible()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible()) API method to hide selected columns  based on your condition.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function(settings){
        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );

        // Replace with your actual condition
        var showColumn = Math.round(Math.random()) ? true : false;

        api.columns([4, 5]).visible(showColumn);
    }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ajtc8g7s/) for code and demonstration.

#### Ajax-sourced data

Handle [`xhr`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event fired when an Ajax request is completed. Use [`columns().visible()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible()) API method to hide selected columns based on your condition.

For example:

```
$('#example').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );

    // Replace with your actual condition
    var showColumn = Math.round(Math.random()) ? true : false;

    api.columns([4, 5]).visible(showColumn);
});

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays.json'
});
```

In the above example, `json` variable holds response from the server which you can use to define your condition for showing/hiding columns.

Also please note that `xhr` event handler has to be defined **BEFORE** you call `DataTable()`.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/pg6fztxL/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: But it will run at once. it will not affected if reload datatable, mean with condition

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isVisibleColumns = condition == true ? true : false;
    
    $('#datatable').DataTable({
            serverSide:true,
            processing:true,
            ajax: url,
            columns:[
    
                { data:'Name' , name: 'name' , visible : isVisibleColumns },
                { data:'Address' , name: 'address' ,visible : isVisibleColumns },
    
            ],
    
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ajax:

First get the table:

```
let datatable = $('#table-recaptures').DataTable();
```

Then get the column: //The zero in this case

```
let column_zero = datatable.column( 0 );
```

Later, for ocult

```
 `column.visible( false )`;
```

For visible

```
column.visible( true);
```